# Lazy loader doesn't work properly while not debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

This is what happens in my program: In one place I open a context, fill the database with data, close the context.

In the next place in the program, I open the context again, pull data from the database into the cache (this is my class), and perform some operations with it.

If you view the execution of the program step by step in debug mode, the lazy loader works as it should, all related data is loaded and the work proceeds correctly. If you remove the endpoints and run the program, an error appears:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "An error was generated for warning
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning':
> An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation
> 'TrackedClanProxy.ClanMembers' after the associated DbContext was
> disposed. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event
> ID 'CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning' to the
> 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
> 'AddDbContext'."

I work with entity framework core 7.0.5 and also using efc proxies the same version.

My project is quite complex in terms of dependencies and database structure, so I won’t attach large pieces of code, but here are the pieces as proof that my code seems to comply with the rules for using EF Core.

This is the place in my context where I enable the lazy loader:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     optionsBuilder
         .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
         .UseSqlite(ConnectionString);
}
```

And this is my class, which I first properly fill and put in the database, and then I try to pull out all the data associated with TrackedClan. As you can see - fields are public, virtual.

```
public class TrackedClan
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
     public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
     public string Tag { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<ClanMember> ClanMembers { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<ClanWar> ClanWars { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<CapitalRaid> CapitalRaids { get; set; }

    public TrackedClan()
    {
         ClanMembers = new HashSet<ClanMember>();
         ClanWars = new HashSet<ClanWar>();
         CapitalRaids = new HashSet<CapitalRaid>();
     }
 }
```

Initially, I tried to do without this foreach cycle (code downside) with the clumsy assignment of clan wars capital raids and clan members, but I decided that this could help (although these related entities themselves have their own sub-entities inside, I don’t think this is the right approach - explicitly assigning everything top down).

I tried setting the context not only as

```
using var db = new AppDbContext("path");,
```

But also like

```
using (AppDbContextdb = new AppDbContext("path", true)){ }
```

But that didn’t help either)
And of course I tried googling everything that was at least somewhat similar to my problem.

I don’t really understand how this is possible - when you monitor the contents of a variable through debugging, everything is fine, as soon as you turn away, the program breaks. Some kind of schrödinger`s lazy loader -__-

```
// Here I store data from database into a static class field
public class Cash
{
    public static List<TrackedClan> TrackedClans { get; set; } = new List<TrackedClan>();

    static Cash()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cash initializing started...");

        CashInit();

        Console.WriteLine("Cash initializing successful");
    }

    private static void CashInit()
    {
        using var db = new AppDbContext("Data Source=./../../../../CustomSolutionElements/CoCStatsTracker.db");

        TrackedClans = db.TrackedClans.ToList();

        foreach (var clan in TrackedClans)
        {
            clan.ClanWars = db.ClanWars.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
            clan.CapitalRaids = db.CapitalRaids.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
            clan.ClanMembers = db.ClanMembers.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
        }

        db.Complete();
     }
}

// Another place where I try to obtain it:

  foreach (var member in Cash.TrackedClans.First(x => x.Tag == "#YPPGCCY8").ClanMembers)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(@$"{member.Name}");
  }
```

All I need from this section of the program is to put the TrackedClans entity and everything associated with it into the TrackdClans static field of my Cash class, so that in further work I do not need to open the context again. How can I best implement this?

Well, in addition - it would be nice to know why in the debug, but I remind you that the db context is already closed, the save change is called, I access this static field from an external class - I still see all the related entities, and not only see, but the program works correctly too, but if you remove the end points (run debug in the same mode) - it no longer works? Really magic

Comment: I would be very grateful if someone has an answer)

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? If you're trying to access a navigation property on an entity outside of `CashInit` that's probably why you get that exception.

Comment: @Xerillio An exception is thrown by the line where the forich cycle begins (the line number is unfortunately not indicated here). Yes, I'm trying to access a property marked virtual, but I've already initialized it beforehand, right? As I understand, or rather as I expect, I no longer need the dbcontext, I want to work only with the “fully packaged” static trackedClans property. The question was how can I ensure that it is filled with all connections after closing the context?

Comment: Which of the two `foreach` loop's first line do you mean, perhaps you can add a C# /*comment*/ to the line throwing it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in `CashInit` now is effectively explicit loading. You query the tracked clans, then you query the child collections and assign them explicitely. You could do this more easily by using `Include`

Then, you save the result and the context is disposed. With the context, the information that the child collections have been fetched from the database already is gone (or possibly it was never explicitely set because of the way you loaded the entities). You access clan members later on, the lazy loading proxy attempts to fetch it from the database and fails because the database context has already been disposed.

In the debugger, you would still see the loaded entities though and it would appear normal.

In the code given here, you could simply remove the lazy loading proxies, since you load the data explicitely. If you do not need lazy loading somewhere in your project, this is what I would recommend.
You can also try if loading the entities another way, either by using `Include` or by using explicit loading with `context.Entry(..).Collection(..).Load()` as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit
helps to keep the information that these entities are already loaded and don't need to be lazy loaded.
I haven't used lazy loading for a while and am not 100% sure on the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All I need is to load all related data once into my static field so that during further work I do not have to open data contexts at the business logic level, but can simply access this field from the outside.
Do I understand correctly that I don’t need a lazy loader at all (It is good when the databases are simply huge and you need to be careful with memory, and all actions are carried out using dbcontext{}) and it’s better to set everything explicitly through Include or somehow using context.Entry? 
(followed the link, got the gist, but haven’t tried it yet)

Comment: Generally: If you need the child collections for the majority of entries, use eager loading with `Include`. It cuts down on database round trips and all the relevant data is in memory. This is assuming that data is not too large to be held in memory.

If that should be the case, or you only need the child collections for a few entries of the list, you can use lazy or explicit loading. They both serve the same purpose, getting selected child entities from the db later. Lazy loading is just implicit about the need for a dbcontext to get those entities, while explicit loading is... explicit.

Comment: Thanks for answers! We still haven’t figured out why the program worked when I went through the debug line by line, but didn’t work without it, but now at least we know how to make it work properly)

Answer (score 0):

So this application is essentially loading the entire database into memory. For a smaller set of data, Ok, but if that dataset size grows this will get expensive and ultimately impossible.. However, assuming a relatively small, simple application:

replace this:

```
    TrackedClans = db.TrackedClans.ToList();

    foreach (var clan in TrackedClans)
    {
        clan.ClanWars = db.ClanWars.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
        clan.CapitalRaids = db.CapitalRaids.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
        clan.ClanMembers = db.ClanMembers.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
    }
```

With this:

```
TrackedClans = db.TrackedClans
    .Include(x => x.ClanMembers)
    .Include(x => x.ClanWars)
    .Include(x => x.CapitalRaids)
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ASNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

This should load all of your data using 4 queries rather than loading tracked clans, then for each row, running 3 more queries to get the related items for that row.

Your code does not/cannot make use of lazy loading since lazy loading can only occur while entities are still within the scope of the DbContext that read them. Once the DbContext is disposed, lazy calls cannot be made.

The difference in behavior you are seeing with the debugger is likely the fact that while debugging and inspecting your entities while within the scope of the DBContext, that "touch" is ensuring that the proxies that EF creates around your entity classes are resolving their references to the other entities that were loaded individually.

When it comes to loading entities you never want to "Set" collection references. They should be initialized and never touched after that. So code like this:

```
    clan.ClanWars = db.ClanWars.Where(x => x.TrackedClanId == clan.Id).ToList();
```

... on an entity should be avoided. If you did hypothetically want to trigger lazy loading then you could do this:

```
TrackedClans = db.TrackedClans.ToList();
foreach(var clan in TrackedClans)
{
    _ = clan.ClanWars.ToList();
    _ = clan.CapitalRaids.ToList();
    _ = clan.ClanMembers.ToList();
}
```

This "touches" each navigation collection and would trigger their lazy load. That said, ***do not*** do this as a solution, it is for explanation purposes only! :) This would essentially do what your original code was attempting but via the lazy loading proxy. If you have 100 clans, this will result in 301 queries to the database, where eager loading with `AsSplitQuery` will result in 4 queries no matter how many clans are present.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great comment! I already reached some points myself, but it was still useful)